# Что характеризует тактовая частота процессора?

Tags: железо, процессор

Не могу разобраться в понятии тактовой частоты. На большинстве сайтов представлены такие определения: *Тактовая частота ― число выполненных операций в секунд; Тактовая частота — частота синхронизирующих импульсов синхронной электронной схемы*. Недавно прочел книгу Петцольда 'Код', где в одной из схем в качестве генератора тактовых импульсов использовался осциллятор, в этой же схеме был представлен счетчик, который считал эти импульсы и как бы 'бегал' по ячейкам памяти, тем самым адресуя байты из ОЗУ в процессор. Можно ли сказать, что тактовая частота процессора характеризует скорость, с которой процессор способен извлечь команду из памяти (или ее часть) и выполнить ее?

Comment: Кажется всё-таки частота доступа процессора к памяти и частота выполнения инструкций процессора могут быть разными.

Comment: Скорее,  тактовая частота характеризует скорость, с которой процессор исполняет уже выбранные из памяти команды. Только надо иметь в виду, что современный процессор делает много вещей одновременно. Например, читает  память, исполняет части нескольких ранее выбранных команд, вычисляет адрес следующей исполняемой команды и т.п. (Хотел подробней расписать, но понял, что придется писать всего очень много и решил поискать в инете).  Вот [тут](https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/343566/) в начале статьи вроде бы кое-что популярно изложено